# onClick function works without click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm stuck with a problem on my ReactJS code causes an `onClick` error that I can't understand.

```
<button onClick={this.apiGetProductPicture(this.props.categorie)}>{this.props.name}</button>
```

If I write it like this (with no parameters it works)

```
<button onClick={this.apiGetProductPicture()}>{this.props.name}</button>
```

But with parameters, the function works when I load the page and do not need to click...

An example of how I give the parameter.

```
<ProductItem name={"Boulangerie"} categorie={0} />
```

I already search but don't understand why function start without permission.

Function:

```
    apiGetProductPicture(i) {
    console.log('apiGetProductPicture');
    var json = myApiGet('https://******')
        // TODO do something with the data
        .then(json => this.setState({ pictures: json.content.categories[1].background }))

        .catch(error => console.log('home2', error));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to give the reference of a function on the onClick:

So you have to write something like it :

```
apiGetProductPicture= (i) => () => {
    i = 0;
    console.log('apiGetProductPicture');
    var json = myApiGet('https://******')
        // TODO do something with the data
        .then(json => this.setState({ pictures: json.content.categories[1].background }))

        .catch(error => console.log('home2', error));
}
```

Comment: Omg this work... i suck so much thanks :'(